# Why is it possible to change the visibility of a virtual member or a public base class?

Tags: c++, oop

Browsing in a code base I found something on the line of:

```
class Interface{
    public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface{
    protected:
    void func() override {};
};
```

I thought that would have been a compilation error, but it seems it is not. What sense does it make?

Comment: Freedom. Sometimes it may be _kind of useful_ (for example if you want to hide a member you want to discourage to be used). At least when they access through derived class. See it as kind of "explicit implementation". That said it's so weak and confusing that I would avoid it without exceptions.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to go from private to public than vice-versa.

Comment: @Simple Why? Going from private to public makes no sense.

Comment: @BЈовић if you have a private member function then maybe you want to expose it as part of your interface, so you make it public. I find saner than going from public -> private, where you can just use a cast to get around it.

Comment: @Simple In such case, you can not use the base class as the interface for the object. You would always have to case to derived, and that is bad.

Comment: @BЈовић to clarify, I don't think either is sensible. I just think that private > public is saner than public > private. But whatever, this is never done in practice.

Comment: @Simple Of course it is. The OP found it in his code base. Also this is kind of NVI design pattern.

Comment: @BЈовић & Simple: For what it's worth, Java allows protected -> public but forbids public -> protected ([demo](http://ideone.com/810sRz)), and I think PHP chose to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What sense does it make?

Yes, it makes sense. If you try to create object of Derived type, you will not be able to call that method. So the idea is to always access the object through it's interface.

The idea is to enforce the [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
protected:
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "foo 1" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct Derived2 : Base
{
protected:
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "foo 2" << std::endl;
    }
};


void wouldFail()
{
    Derived1 d;


    // d.foo(); -- Error! Do not try to call it directly
}

void ok()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Base > > v;

    v.emplace_back( std::make_shared<Derived1>() );
    v.emplace_back( std::make_shared<Derived2>() );

    for ( auto & it : v )
        it->foo();
}

int main()
{
    wouldFail();
    ok();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++:

- *accessibility* is a “static” notion (checked at compile-time), whereas
- *virtual dispatch* is a “dynamic” notion (the implementation to call is chosen at run-time).

We can say that C++ keeps those two notions “orthogonal”.

So with your example, this will compile (not realistic code, just illustration):

```
Implementation obj;
Interface& ref = obj;
ref.func(); // (will call obj.func())
```

but this won't:

```
Implementation obj;
obj.func(); // error: Implementation::func is protected
```

effectively “forcing” you to only use the interface (which maybe was the intent). — *Edit:* see [Dieter Lücking's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20470307) for a maybe better design.

Comment: An even better design would have been to not allow virtual functions' visibility to be changed.

Comment: @PaulManta One could argue about that, but anyway I was referring to “coding design” (by the programmer) while you are referring to “language design” (by Bjarne Stroustrup and/or the ISO C++ committee)

Answer (score 1):

Freedom. Sometimes it may be *kind of useful* (for example if you want to hide a member you want to discourage to be used). At least when they access through derived class.

See it as kind of "explicit implementation". Let's say, for example, you have a base interface `List` like this (very simplified code for illustration purposes):

```
class List {
public:
    virtual void add(std::string item) = 0;
    virtual std::string at(int index) = 0;
};
```

You create your `ReadOnlyList` concrete class which implements `List` interface, in this case you would discourage users of your class to call `add()` method, just change its visibility. Unless they're accessing it through `List` interface it'll  be hidden.

Another example? If you want to provide an interface for some specific tasks but it's an implementation detail and it's **not part of class contract**. In this case you make them protected or private and they won't be accessible.

That said it's so weak and confusing that I would avoid to do it, besides very few, commented and well controlled exceptions.